# Find the top 5 highest number in an matrix of 4x5

Tags: matlab, matrix, max

There are 12 numbers present in an 4x3 matrix and I need to find out the top 5 highest numbers among them.
For example,

```
B=[11 13 21;10 8 5;3 2 6;7 18 6]
```

Thus the top 5 highest numbers should be

```
ans=[21;18;13;11;10]
```

How could I go about doing it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sort the data:

```
Bsorted = sort(B(:), 'descend');
```

And pick the top 5:

```
Btop5 = Bsorted(1:5);
```