# Pick x smallest elements in Matlab

Tags: matlab, matrix, minimum

I have a matrix of integer values, the x axis represent different days and y axis represents hour of the day. And in each cell is a **number** that indicates how many hours of the day of the day correspond some criteria of the day which is just going on. That's why I need to calculate it for every hour and not only at the end of the time.

The whole issue is I have then to pick 5 best days which have the lowest number (least corresponding). So basically in the matrix it means **select 5 lowest numbers in the row** and **remember the indexes of the columns** where the minimum is. (I need to know in which day it occured). Because at every time as the time goes on it can be 5 different days so sorting the whole table would do mess.

I can make it work really ugly by taking first 5 number and then when if I find smaller one on the way I will forget biggest one from the 5 and remember the index of the column for the new one. Yet this solution seems to be pretty sloppy. There has to be a better way in Matlab how to solve this.

Any ideas, functions that can make my life easier?

1   1   0   1   1   1   0   0   1   1

1   2   1   2   2   1   0   1   2   2

For example in these two rows indexed from 1-10, in the first row it should return columns
3,7,8 and two others not really caring which one.
In the second row it should return columns 7,8,6,1,3.

Comment: Please provide sample input and desired output.

Comment: I don't understand from the question why you can't sort the matrix by rows.

Comment: well basically because every time I would sort the table I would have to keep also the indexes for the columns and next row will have different columns as minimum so you would make a lot of sorting plus keeping indexes which would not really be efficient.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Find the top 5 highest number in an matrix of 4x5](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15173257/find-the-top-5-highest-number-in-an-matrix-of-4x5)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to find the index of the n smallest elements in a vector](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14140746/how-to-find-the-index-of-the-n-smallest-elements-in-a-vector)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
A = randi(60,100,2);
[min_val,index] = sort(A(:,2),'ascend');    
output = [A(index(1:5),1) A(index(1:5),2)];
```

this should help you (I guess);

Answer (score 1):

Probably one of the simplest (but not most efficient) way is to use the `sort` function (which also returns sorted indices):

```
>> [~,index] = sort([1 1 0 1 1 1 0 0 1 1]);
>> index(1:5)
ans =

     3     7     8     1     2

>> [~,index] = sort([1 2 1 2 2 1 0 1 2 2]);
>> index(1:5)

ans =

     7     1     3     6     8
```